# System.IndexOutOfRangeException throwing on a string

Tags: string, vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

in my current project I encounter the above exception when trying to set the string "stringWriter" to "" or Nothing. Furthermore, this also occurred when trying to set it to any other value.

Primarily, I am confused as I have done the above many times previously and not encountered the exception and secondly when I do get this exception it is always with arrays and I am unsure about how it fits in in the context of strings.

Here is the relevant code in Visual Basic:

```
Using FileReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(TrainingData)
                Do Until FileReader.EndOfStream
                    ReDim inputTrain(inputLayerSize, lineCount)
                    ReDim outputTarget(outputLayerSize, lineCount)

                    Dim x As Integer = 0
                    Dim i As Integer = 0

                    line = FileReader.ReadLine()

                    Do Until i > inputLayerSize
                        charReader = line.Substring(x, 1)

                        If charReader = "," Then
                            i += 1
                            inputTrain(i, lineCount) = Convert.ToDouble(stringWriter)

                            stringWriter = ""
                        Else
                            stringWriter += charReader
                        End If
                        x += 1
                    Loop
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

For context, the project is a neural network and this is the subroutine that will load the training data from a text file separated by commas. "charReader" is the currently selected character in the "line", the line in the .txt file being read. "stringWriter" is what charReader is being appended to and when a comma is detected the contents of stringWriter is converted into a double and stored in, in this example, "inputTrain(,)". The exception occurs on the line

```
stringWriter = ""
```

Any and all help is appreciated, if this is too vague I am happy to provide more context.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't occurring on the previous line when `i` is greater than `inputLayerSize` ?

Comment: It might be throwing the error at the charReader = line.Substring(x,1). 
If your line doesn't contain any text it might go out of bounds.